# Book API for in stores available book

Tags: web-apps

Looking for API where books can look up. I want to pass a keyword and get back list of book titles and thumbnails. Like Rotten Tomatoes for movies. I want to use it for book recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Goodreads API](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index)

Goodreads has an API that allows you to fetch all sorts of information about books. You can access them when you register for a developer key. Below is the one that matches your question:

> **Get the reviews for a book given a title string**
>
> Get an xml response that contains embed code for the iframe reviews widget, which shows an excerpt (first 300 characters) of the most popular reviews of a book for a given title/author. The book shown will be the most popular book that matches all the keywords in the input string. The reviews are from all known editions of the book.
>
> URL: https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.FORMAT    (sample url)
>
> HTTP method: GET
>
> Parameters:
>
> format: xml or json
>
> key: Developer key (required).
>
> title: The title of the book to lookup.
>
> author: The author name of the book to lookup. This is optional, but is recommended for accuracy.
>
> rating: Show only reviews with a particular rating (optional)